# How to Create nested collection map<text,list<text>> type in cassandra database 2.2.1

Tags: dictionary, collections, cassandra, nested, cql3

```
create table tbl_master_values (
  dbid int primary key,
  user_dbid int, reg_dbid int,
  module_dbid int,
  fields_value map<text,list<text>>,
  created_date timestamp,
  modified_date timestamp);
```

It returns this error:

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] 
message="Non-frozen collections are not allowed inside collections: map<text, list<text>>"
```

Comment: There is a type in your script: **fields_value map>**

Comment: @doanduyhai I saw that, too.  Turns out that he had the syntax correct, but the StackOverflow editor incorrectly interpreted his angle brackets.

Answer (score 4):

In Cassandra, you can use non-frozen collections if you intend to add or remove entries through in-Cassandra query. But when you intend to use UDT or nested collection inside your map, you must declare former as frozen.
For example in your case:

```
    create table tbl_master_values (
    dbid int primary key,
    user_dbid int, reg_dbid int,
    module_dbid int,
    fields_value map<text,frozen<list<text>>>,
    created_date timestamp,
    modified_date timestamp);
```

If you are using Map for storing and retrieving information, and not updating the row you can declare it as:

```
    frozen<map<text, list<text>>>
```

Remember frozen<> keyword will not let you update that entity and store it as blob type.
Read here for clarification on updating:

> https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertMap.html

Comment: How to query list from map and check if it contains a value?

Answer (score 3):

> Non-frozen collections are not allowed inside collections: map>

Cassandra is telling you that it cannot complete the operation without using the [frozen](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/collection_type_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_exb_vg5_yj__using-frozen-in-collection) keyword.

```
fields_value frozen<map<text, list<text>>>,
```

Keep in mind that [frozen](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/collection_type_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_exb_vg5_yj__using-frozen-in-collection) tells Cassandra to treat the value as a blob, and prevents individual parts of the value from being modified.  When you make a change to a frozen collection you are serializing and rewriting all of the items stored.  So this probably won't be a good solution for a frequently-changing collection.

Comment: It's ok, but can't search value of list. and also can't create index on it.